# Pandas Dataframe: Count and Bin integers and datetime into ranges producing two output dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, count, label, bin

I have the Following Dataframe:

```
ID  Minutes Datetime
1   30      6/4/2018  23:47:00 
2   420 
3   433     6/10/2018 2:50 
4   580     6/9/2018 3:10
5   1020
```

I want to count the number of times the Minutes occur between a certain range.  I want to do a similar count for datetime field (timestamp falls within certain range of time).

Below is the output I want:

```
MIN_RANGE   COUNT   
6-8 hours   2
8-10 hours  1
10-12 hours 0
12-14 hours 0
14-16 hours 0
16+ hours   1



RANGE        COUNT  
8pm - 10pm   0
10pm - 12am  1
12am - 2am   0
2am-4am      2    
4am-6am      0
6am-8am      0
8am -10am    0
10am - 12pm  0
12pm - 2pm   0
2pm - 4pm    0
4pm - 6pm    0
6pm - 8pm    0
```

I have searched around google and stackoverflow on how to do this (searching bins and stuff) but couldn't find anything directly related to what I am trying to do.

Help?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 5):

This is a complex problem that can be achieved by using `pd.date_range` and `pd.cut`, and then some index manipulation.

First of all, you can start by *cutting* your data frame using `pd.cut`

```
cuts = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime), pd.date_range('02:00:00', freq='2H', periods=13))

0             (2018-07-09 22:00:00, 2018-07-10]
1                                           NaN
2    (2018-07-09 02:00:00, 2018-07-09 04:00:00]
3    (2018-07-09 02:00:00, 2018-07-09 04:00:00]
4                                           NaN
```

This will yield the cuts based on your `Datetime` column and the ranges defined.

Lets start by having a `base` data frame with values set to 0, such that we will update it later with your counts. Using your `cuts` from above,

```
cats = cuts.cat.categories

bases = ["{}-{}".format(v.left.strftime("%H%p"),v.right.strftime("%H%p")) for v in cats]
df_base = pd.DataFrame({"Range": bases, "Count":0}).set_index("Range")
```

which yields

```
            COUNT
Range   
02AM-04AM   0
04AM-06AM   0
06AM-08AM   0
08AM-10AM   0
10AM-12PM   0
12PM-14PM   0
14PM-16PM   0
16PM-18PM   0
18PM-20PM   0
20PM-22PM   0
22PM-00AM   0
00AM-02AM   0
```

Now, you can use `collections.Counter` to quickly count your occurrences

```
x = Counter(cuts.dropna())
```

Notice that I have used `dropna()` not to count `NaN`s. With your `x` variable, we can

```
values = {"{}-{}".format(k.left.strftime("%H%p"), k.right.strftime("%H%p")) : v for k,v in x.items()}
counts_df = pd.DataFrame([values]).T
```

which yields

```
            0
02AM-04AM   2
22PM-00AM   1
```

Finally, we just *update* our previous data frame with these values

```
df_base.loc[counts_df.index, "Count"] = counts_df[0]

            COUNT
Range   
02AM-04AM   2
04AM-06AM   0
06AM-08AM   0
08AM-10AM   0
10AM-12PM   0
12PM-14PM   0
14PM-16PM   0
16PM-18PM   0
18PM-20PM   0
20PM-22PM   0
22PM-00AM   1
00AM-02AM   0
```

Comment: I cannot believe this answer earned you just 4 upvotes

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
counts = np.histogram(df['Minutes'],
     bins = list(range(6*60,18*60,2*60))+[24*60])[0]
bin_labels = [ '6-8 hours',
                '8-10 hours',
                '10-12 hours',
                '12-14 hours',
                '14-16 hours',
                '16+ hours']
pd.Series(counts, index = bin_labels)
```

You can do a similar thing with the hours, using the `hour` attribute of datetime objects. You will have to fill in the empty parts of the `Datetime` column first.

Comment: when i run the code, I get the following error: NameError: name 'bin_labels' is not defined

Comment: @PineNuts0 Yeah, I spelled the variable name different in different places. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

@RafaelC has already addressed the binning and counting, but I'll make a note about reading the data from a file.

First, let's assume you separate your columns by commas (CSV), and start with:

`dates.csv`

```
ID,Minutes,Datetime
1,30,6/4/2018  23:47:00 
2,420,
3,433,6/10/2018 2:50 
4,580,6/9/2018 3:10
5,1020,
```

Then, you can read the values and parse the third column as dates as follows.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def my_date_parser(date_str):
    # Allow empty values to be coerced to NaT (Not a Time)
    # rather than throw an exception
    return pd.to_datetime(date_str, errors='coerce')

df = pd.read_csv(
    './dates.csv', 
    date_parser=my_date_parser, 
    parse_dates=['Datetime']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get also get the counts by using the built in `floor` attribute of `datetime` objects. In this case, you want to use the frequency of `'2h'` so that you are looking at 2 hour bins. Then just grab the `time` part

```
import pandas as pd

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df.Datetime.dt.floor('2h').dt.time
#0    22:00:00
#1         NaT
#2    02:00:00
#3    02:00:00
#4         NaT
```

(Alternatively you could also just use `df.Datetime.dt.hour//2` to get the same grouping logic, but slightly different labels)

So you can easily just groupby this and then count:

```
df.groupby(df.Datetime.dt.floor('2h').dt.time).size()
#Datetime
#02:00:00    2
#22:00:00    1
#dtype: int64
```

Now to get the full list, we can just reindex, and change the index labels to be a bit more informative.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

df_counts = df.groupby(df.Datetime.dt.floor('2h').dt.time).size()

ids = [datetime.time(2*x,0) for x in range(12)]
df_counts = df_counts.reindex(ids).fillna(0).astype('int')

# Appropriately label the ranges with more info if needed
df_counts.index = '['+df_counts.index.astype(str) + ' - ' + np.roll(df_counts.index.astype(str), -1)+')'
```

## Output:

`df_counts`

```
[00:00:00 - 02:00:00)    0
[02:00:00 - 04:00:00)    2
[04:00:00 - 06:00:00)    0
[06:00:00 - 08:00:00)    0
[08:00:00 - 10:00:00)    0
[10:00:00 - 12:00:00)    0
[12:00:00 - 14:00:00)    0
[14:00:00 - 16:00:00)    0
[16:00:00 - 18:00:00)    0
[18:00:00 - 20:00:00)    0
[20:00:00 - 22:00:00)    0
[22:00:00 - 00:00:00)    1
dtype: float64
```